# Looking for a Product Management (Mass Updates) Extension w/ Some Key Features

Tags: magento2, extensions

Looking for an extension where I can import / export / make mass updates to existing products. Needs to have the following features:

- Exports nicely into excel. The current stock Magento export has only csv option which causes unplanned column breaks (because some of our data has commas in it)
- Has the ability to change the actual SKUs of products in bulk (I currently can't do this with Magento's stock import / export due to "SKU" being the primary key).
- Has the ability to import new attribute options. For example, if I currently have the attribute "color" with the following options: red, green, blue. Then I get some new products, and one they have colors of orange, yellow, brown, white, etc. Right now I have to go in and manually add new options one by one. Would like to do it via upload.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a specific plugin that offers you all of your desired features at a single place. However, those functions can be performed by different plugins:

1. [Mass Product Import & Update](https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/mass-product-update-import-magento.html): The plugin allows you to export
   nicely to CSVs. You are very unlikely to face the issue of column
   breaks.
2. [Store Manager for Magento](https://www.mag-manager.com/): You can bulk update SKUs via Multi
   Editor. You can find the steps to do it right [here](https://www.mag-manager.com/useful-articles/how-to/how-to-bulk-update-magento-product-skus/).
3. [Import Export Attribute Options](https://marketplace.magento.com/emipro-importexportattributeoption.html): You can use it to import
   hundreds of attribute options within a single click using a CSV
   file.

Comment: Looks like Mass Product Import and Update can actually do #2 and #3, BUT their support told me its not a tool for export.